# group_by_month(:date).select() not giving date value in the desired output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by, group

I am using the following code to group my active record relation by month. But as I extract attributes, I do not know how to get the date value as well.

This is my code:

```rb
books.group_by_month(:date).select("COUNT(*) as total, SUM(first_attribute) as fa").as_json
```

The output for the same is:

```rb
[
  {"total"=>273, "fb"=>2864977652, "id"=>nil}, 
  {"total"=>370, "fb"=>3882834096, "id"=>nil}, 
  {"total"=>37, "fb"=>300460723, "id"=>nil}
]
```

How will I know which hash is for which month, how can I include the month data in my query as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
books.select("COUNT(*) as total, SUM(first_attribute) as fa").group_by { |record| record.date.strftime('%m') }
```

Answer (score 0):

If not to use method `group_by_month` from `groupdate` gem you can do it this way:

```rb
books.select(
  "COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(first_attribute) AS fa, to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') AS month"
).group(:month)

# output

[
  {"total"=>273, "fb"=>2864977652, "month" => "2022-06", "id"=>nil}, 
  {"total"=>370, "fb"=>3882834096, "month" => "2022-05", "id"=>nil}, 
  {"total"=>37, "fb"=>300460723, "month" => "2021-06", "id"=>nil}
]
```